# How to download whole folder that contain year several files with number at the beggining of its name?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to download all .zip's files from this page:

https://danepubliczne.imgw.pl/data/dane_pomiarowo_obserwacyjne/dane_meteorologiczne/dobowe/synop/2011/

I'm using:

```
library(rvest) 

URL <- paste0("https://danepubliczne.imgw.pl/data/dane_pomiarowo_obserwacyjne/dane_meteorologiczne/dobowe/synop/2011/")

rh <- read_html(URL)
zips <- grep("zip$", html_attr(html_nodes(pg, "a[href^='2011']"), "href"), value=TRUE)
```

but the zips variable is empty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With download_html (URL) you can download the page and you will see the name of all the zips; from there, you can build the URLs and download them.

Comment: I already tried it before but it returns only the year number.

Comment: No, you can see: <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/compressed.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="2011_185_s.zip">2011_185_s.zip</a></td><td align="right">2017-11-15 12:52  </td><td align="right"> 16K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>  and you can mount the urls https://danepubliczne.imgw.pl/data/dane_pomiarowo_obserwacyjne/dane_meteorologiczne/dobowe/synop/2011/2011_115_s.zip

Comment: That's strange but download_html doesn't do nothing for me. However I went for html_parse so I got the given output. Thank you for help!

Comment: Surely download_html, you are downloading a file.